# Generate a matrix with increasing values but NaN along the main diagonal?

Tags: matlab, matrix

There is likely a quick little trick for this problem, but I cannot find it. I would like code to produce the matrix in the following image:

[image: Example matrix]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way using logical indexing:

```
n = 4;
A = nan(n);
A(~eye(n)) = 1:n^2-n;    %// Only replace values *not* on diagonal
A = A.'

A =

   NaN     1     2     3
     4   NaN     5     6
     7     8   NaN     9
    10    11    12   NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using [`triu`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html) and [`tril`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html):

```
n = 4;
A = reshape(1:n*(n-1),n-1,n).';
z = zeros(n,1);
A = [tril(A,-1) z]+[z triu(A)]+diag(NaN(n,1));
```

which, in this case for a 4-by-4 matrix, returns

```
A =

   NaN     1     2     3
     4   NaN     5     6
     7     8   NaN     9
    10    11    12   NaN
```

Here's another way just using [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
n = 4;
A = [reshape(1:n*(n-1),n,n-1);NaN(1,n-1)];
A = reshape([NaN;A(:)],n,n).'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

```
n = 4; %// matrix size
x = 1-eye(n);
x(:) = cumsum(x(:));
x = x.' + diag(NaN(1,n));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start from a `nan` matrix, find the linear indices of the diagonal, then fill up the rest of the elements with an incrementing range:

```
n=4;
A=nan(n);
inds=setdiff(1:n^2,sub2ind([n,n],1:n,1:n));
A(inds)=1:numel(inds);
A=A.'; %' transpose to get the matrix we need
```

The transpose in the end is necessary, as linear indexing goes *column-first*, but your specifics need a row-first assignment of matrix elements.

Result:

```
>> A
A =
   NaN     1     2     3
     4   NaN     5     6
     7     8   NaN     9
    10    11    12   NaN
```